# xml array doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have this xml files:

```
<product    
<EANCode EAN="5053973641331"/>
```

I use this to assign value

```
  $prodean=$XMLarray['Product']['EANCode']['@attributes'];
  $ean1[0]=$prodean['EAN'];
```

and it work fine.
But when I have more EAN value, for example

```
<EANCode EAN="5053973641331"/>
<EANCode EAN="7301433035830"/>
<EANCode EAN="0730143303583"/>
<EANCode EAN="0730143303378"/>
<EANCode EAN="5053118731828"/>
<EANCode EAN="5053973635132"/>
```

it's doens't work.
Where is my mistake?

I want always the first EAN value. I have it if in the xml file there are only one EAN value, but if there are two or more value I have NULL for $ean1[0]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is expected and actual behaviour?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I want always the first EAN value. I have it if in the xml file there are only one EAN value, but if there are two or more value I have NULL for $ean1[0]

Comment: So describe it in your question, because at it currently is, it is difficult to say what you are asking about.

Comment: Does `$prodean=$XMLarray['Product']['EANCode'][0]['@attributes'];`work?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak It work conversely. If I have two value work fine, only one it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example. I have test your code and its a bit tricky.

```
$xml = '<products>
<EANCode EAN="5053973641331"/>
<EANCode EAN="7301433035830"/>
<EANCode EAN="0730143303583"/>
<EANCode EAN="0730143303378"/>
<EANCode EAN="5053118731828"/>
<EANCode EAN="5053973635132"/>
</products>';

$XMLarray = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($XMLarray->EANCode as $xml) {
    echo $xml->attributes()['EAN']."<br>";
}
```

So with your xml example:

http://data.icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/IT/8952561.xml

My code is not working because you have a node called "Product" so you should access them first. Then it should be possible to get the data.

```
$XMLarray = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("test.xml"));
foreach($XMLarray->Product->EANCode as $xml) {
    echo $xml->attributes()['EAN']."<br>";
}
```

i have put your xml to a file test.xml and that code is working.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work for me. Maybe because I have another xmlarray before?  $prod=$XMLarray['Product']['@attributes'];

Comment: If you have another structure the code is not working but you can adopt it to your problem ;)

Comment: When you load the XML you are in the first element and you have to foreach strough all child elements. Then you can access that values with the attributes function.

Comment: ok but there is no difference between your code and this one: foreach($XMLarray['Product']['EANCode'] as $test1){
   $ean1[$i]=$test1['@attributes']['EAN'];
   }                                                                                                               right?

Comment: maybe my problem is on this type of array? $xml = simplexml_load_string($util->getJson($_POST['linkXML']));
$json = json_encode($xml);
$XMLarray = json_decode($json,TRUE);

Comment: Sorry i can't help your without the correct XML structure ;)

Comment: please see: http://openIcecat-xml:freeaccess@data.icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/IT/8952561.xml

Comment: If I want to set a variable for frist value of EAN I can do? foreach($XMLarray['Product']['EANCode'] as $test1){ $ean1[$i]=$test1['@attributes']['EAN']; } is not the same of your code? I take $ean1[0] for frist value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file = 'http://openIcecat-xml:freeaccess@data.icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/IT/8952561.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
// get first "EANCode" node and its "EAN" attribute
echo $xml->Product->EANCode[0]['EAN'];
```

Hope this helps.